# Scala: What is the difference between filter and takeWhile on a stream?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I just started to learn Scala, and I'm confused between the filter and takeWhile while working on streams.

I came across this program to generate prime numbers, which uses both takeWhile and filter on a stream.

```
lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(i => 
             ps.takeWhile{j => j * j <= i}.forall{ k => i % k > 0});
```

While experimenting i found

```
Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ < 10).toList
```

returns me

```
List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

while

```
 Stream.from(1).filter(_ < 10).toList
```

runs infinitely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference isn't stream-specific, but the same for all collections extending [`GenTraversableLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.collection.GenTraversableLike):

`filter`

> Returns **all the elements** that satisfy the predicate `p`

`takeWhile`

> Returns **the longest prefix** whose elements satisfy the predicate `p`.

E.g.

```
> List(1, 2, 3, 4).filter(_ % 2 == 1)
List(1, 3)

> List(1, 2, 3, 4).takeWhile(_ % 2 == 1)
List(1)
```

In particular, `Stream.from(1).filter(_ < 10).toList` doesn't finish because it has to check every element of the stream: it doesn't "know" there won't be any elements which satisfy `_ < 10` after 9 (and actually, there are, thanks to wraparound).

Answer (score 20):

`takeWhile()` stop evaluation immediately after condition is not met.

`filter` have to evaluate the whole Stream.

I suggest You to analyze this two function in below code:

https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala